How to Interpret RGB Values from an Old Paradox Database?
I’m working with an old Paradox database that stores RGB values for a CORB dispensing machine.enter image description here However, I’m having trouble understanding the RGB values. For example, the integer 38428280 corresponds to the RGB value RGB(122,88,56).
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Integer Value = (Red × 256^2) + (Green × 256) + Blue
But this formula doesn’t seem to work. Can someone help me figure out how to correctly read the RGB values from this database?

Hint: convert 38428280 to binary, and compare to the RGB binary values.  E.g. 56=00111000, 88=01011000,122=011011010.
